# What fault in collision detection implementation causes balls that hit each other to swirl

Tags: ruby, language-agnostic, collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics

Hi I have the following implementation of ball to ball collision detection in ruby, which works fine for most collisions. How ever there are some flaws when balls hit each other at certain angels.

I have put my implementation down here if you need more info tell me. But Im wondering more in general terms. What causes the balls to swirl around each other at certain angels of impact.

```
def ball_collider! ball
        for ball2 in @balls do
          next if ball.object_id == ball2.object_id
          next unless box_overlap ball2.boundbox, ball.boundbox
          next unless ball_overlap ball, ball2
          dx = ball2.x - ball.x
          dy = ball2.y - ball.y
          dist=Math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
          bonuce_point_x = ball2.x - (ball.radii + ball2.radii) * dx / dist
          bonuce_point_y = ball2.y - (ball.radii + ball2.radii) * dy / dist

          bounce_line =  [[bonuce_point_x,bonuce_point_y],[bonuce_point_x-dy,bonuce_point_y+dx]]

          ball2.bounce! bounce_line
          ball.bounce! bounce_line
          motion_left = ball.unmove! bounce_line, true
       ball_controller! ball if motion_left > 0.1
  end
end

def box_overlap box1, box2
  return (box1[:width] + box2[:width] > (box1[:x] - box2[:x]).abs) && (box1[:width] + box2[:width] > (box1[:y] - box2[:y]).abs)
end

def ball_overlap ball1, ball2
  dx = ball2.x - ball1.x
  dy = ball2.y - ball1.y
  return (dx**2 + dy**2) < (ball1.radii+ball2.radii)**2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your physics model, you are presumably updating positions and doing collision checks at discrete time intervals. This means that when you detect a collision between a pair of balls, the actual collision would have taken place somewhat before that time, and your calculations will thus be based on the wrong movement vectors. You could do calculations to get the correct time of impact, but this could get messy due to other objects being involved in collisions with the two objects you're checking within the same time interval. Try increasing the frequency (ie. reducing your time intervals) to limit the problem.

As for why you get the "swirl" effect: the calculations will cause the balls to still be colliding with each other after your modify their vectors, even when they are now moving away from each other, which will again cause your next iteration to pull them towards each other's center again, and so on and so forth.